# Cannot read property 'has' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I was upgrading my Discord bot to Discord.js v12 version but I encountered the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'has' of undefined
```

Here's my code:

```js
if (cmd.conf.permLevel === 4) {
    if (!message.member.permission.has("ADMINISTRATOR")) {
        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
          .setDescription(`Bu komutu kullanabilmek için \`Yönetici\` iznine sahip olmalısın!`)
          .setColor("f5f5f5").setTimestamp();
        message.channel.send({ embed });
        return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error `Cannot read property 'has' of undefined` indicates that you are trying to read `.has` of a variable, which has value `undefined`. In your case, you may guess there is something wrong with `message.member.permission`, because you are trying to read its `.has`.

According to the [official document](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=permissions),
you should use `.permissions` instead of `.permission`.

In conclusion, you should change `message.member.permission.has` to

```js
message.member.permissions.has
                         ^
```

I suggest that every time when you get an error `Cannot read property 'xxx' of undefined`, you should find out which variable is `undefined`, and guess why it is. (It is often caused by a typo)

Comment: Also, there's a more efficient method for what you're trying to do- [`message.member.hasPermission()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=hasPermission)